# how to make ng-change work to change sentence 1 to sentence 2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-v1

thanks for the help.
Sentence1: hello this is java , on click of it it should change to Sentence2: Hello this is not java.

can anyone give me a good solution for this , I have a input tag and check box and there ng-change is working fine , but I want the same logic with text change.

```
<div ng-model="form.app" ng-change="updating()" >  
<input ng-model="form.app" ng-change="updating()" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: The `ng-model` and `ng-change` directives do not work with `<div>` elements.

Comment: then how to achieve this ? I need to change the text from yes to no on click . and when I'm replacing ng-change with ng-click I'm not able to achieve my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to change the text from yes to no on click.

Use [AngularJS expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <input ng-model="form.app" type="checkbox">{{form.app}}
    <div>Hello, this is {{!form.app?'not':''}} Java</div>
</body>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Interpplation and data-binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation).

Comment: I don't want a checkbox like that , I want to click directly on the text itself and make it change.